# Boolean "fix" function. What is it for?

Tags: java, boolean

So I am not exactly sure what to make of this one command strapped to boolean.
The following code was supposed to display (true true) but I don't know how the "fix" function contributes to it:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Example x=new Example();
        x.beginning();
    }

    void beginning() {
        boolean q1=true;
        boolean q2=fix(q1); //here
        System.out.println(q1+" "+q2);
    }

    boolean fix(boolean q1) {     //here again 
        q1=true;
        return q1;
    }
}
```

I don't see people talk about it or use it in their programs. I want to just know what it does so i don't run into problems with it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

On its face, the `fix` method does nothing useful.  Do not copy this method.

---

I imagine you found this class in an article or Q&A that is talking about Java parameter passing semantics.  The entire class is designed to demonstrate that Java parameters are passed by value.

If Java parameters were passed by reference, then the assignment

```
q1 = true;
```

in `fix` would modify the variable `q1` declared in `beginning`.  They aren't and the `q1` declared in `beginning` is not modified.

Thus, the real purpose of `fix` *in context* is to demonstrate that it *doesn't* do something.

---

This is a better version:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Example x = new Example();
        x.beginning();
    }

    void beginning() {
        boolean x1 = false;
        boolean x2 = fix(x1);
        System.out.println(x1 + " " + x2);
    }

    /**
     * If Java is pass by reference, this will "fix" the variable
     * 'x1' in the calling method.
     */
    boolean fix(boolean q) {
        q = true;   // this would change 'x1'
        return q;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's completely useless. `fix()` always returns `true` regardless of what's passed to it. It completely ignores the input argument. It could be equivalently written as:

```
boolean fix(boolean ignored) {
    return true;
}
```

It does nothing useful and there's nothing to learn here. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯